# how to intent to another activity by making clickable TextView in drawable navigation

Tags: android, android-intent

I have make the main part marked with bold (B) I am confused with, where to keep OnClickListner on the code that intent TextView to the new activity.

I want to make clickable menus in navigation drawer. I have login activity. So I want to make login clickable that intents to the login activity.

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

TextView t1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)     findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_search_category) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_login) {

        /*t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nav_login);*/
        t1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){ 
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_register) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_test) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_test1) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_test2) {

    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)     findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `OnClickListener` of the `TextView`. Just do:

```
else if (id == R.id.nav_login) {      
    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: This Works and its that much simple. May be I am new to Android so !!